# Disable Eclipse JSF facet / nature

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf

Eclipse insists on enabling the JSF facet in my project. I can disable it easily enough, but when I run a **Maven -> Update Project** through Eclipse, the facet (and the associated `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file) returns. I'm not referencing JSF in my POM, and there are no JSF jars in my classpath so...

**Why is Eclipse adding the JSF Facet?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be caused by **(a)** the Maven plugin or **(b)** JBoss Tools plugins.

For **(a)** try to:

1. uncheck "JSF Configurator" under

   > Preferences > Maven > Java EE Integration
2. remove the following line from your `.project` file:

   ```
    <nature>org.jboss.tools.jsf.jsfnature</nature>
   ```
3. update the Maven project with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and
4. check the `.project` file again.

Comment: It does not work after doing all the above including deleting away faces-config.xml ....

Comment: @KarenGoh I switched to IntelliJ and cannot check this on the most current version of Eclipse. Maybe there is a new detection mechanism.